# How can I reveal NFTs as they are minted?

Tags: solidity, nft

My goal is to get my reveal function to only reveal the NFT as it gets bought/minted and not reveal the whole collection so that people don't have to wait, however I just keep mucking it up.

Here is what I've got

```
string baseURI;
  string public baseExtension = ".json";
  uint256 public cost = 0.05 ether;
  uint256 public maxSupply = 10000;
  uint256 public maxMintAmount = 20;
  bool public paused = true;
  bool public revealed = false;
  string public notRevealedUri;
  bool public onlyWhitelisted = true;
  address[] public whitelistedAddresses;
  mapping(address => uint256) public addressMintedBalance;
  uint256 public nftPerAddressLimit = 100;
  mapping(uint256 => string) private _tokenURI;
  

  constructor(
    string memory _name,
    string memory _symbol,
    string memory _initBaseURI,
    string memory _initNotRevealedUri
  ) ERC721(_name, _symbol) {
    setBaseURI(_initBaseURI);
    setNotRevealedURI(_initNotRevealedUri);
  }
```

now for the reveal

```
function reveal() public onlyOwner {
      revealed = false;
  }
```

I can't seem to think of a way that would change the bool for specific tokens as they get minted.

My thought was that it should be at the end of the mint function itself, though I am not at all confident in that.

```
for (uint256 i = 1; i <= _mintAmount; i++) {
      addressMintedBalance[msg.sender]++;
      _safeMint(msg.sender, supply + i);
      _tokenURI[supply].revealed = true; <-- *I know this wont work if anyone ever mints more than one at a time.*
    }
```

Comment: What programming language is this?

Comment: I thought I had tagged solidity. My fault

Comment: Hi @grobot do you want admin to only call this function?

Comment: Yes,  I do want that to be an owneronly function, and that it could include some sort of event listener so that if you minted one from my site, it then changes the revealed for that exact NFT automatically

Answer (score 0):

You can include a mapping to hold the reveal states of your nfts. I am not sure whether you intended only admin to call this reveal function every time, in this case this would do!

```
....
mapping(address => mapping(uint256 => bool)) private reveals;


constructor(
string memory _name,
string memory _symbol,
string memory _initBaseURI,
string memory _initNotRevealedUri
    ) ERC721(_name, _symbol) {
    setBaseURI(_initBaseURI);
    setNotRevealedURI(_initNotRevealedUri);
}

function reveal(address _nftContract, uint256 tokenId, bool _reveal) external onlyOwner {
    bool revealed  = reveals[_nftContract][tokenId];
    require(!revealed, 'Token Already revealed');
    reveals[_nftContract][tokenId] = true;

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The best method of doing what I asked, is in fact to not mint any yourself, and have a D-app on a website so that total supply is only that of what has been minted, thus can only point to the baseURI then